# Python process CPU usage going high suddenly. how to detect the place?

Tags: python, cpu

I run multiple (400 python simultaneously)
I start new one each 1.5 sec and repeat round robin
I found that sometimes my CPU usage goes 100%
[image]

While sometimes it is as low as 30%-50%

I need to understand what push it so high, is it the process creation time ?
What should I do to check and debug the spot?

NOTE:
it seems that on steady state where all 400 are running each take 0.2% cpu, so it is only the first 4 seconds of the process, I added a dealy when cput is high.

Comment: Running 400 python processes at once is probably not the best idea. For concurrency and parelelism, look into [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), and [async/await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.